# Alert user to items outside of Array in Extendscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, photoshop, extendscript

I have a script that checks a folder for image files of certain format contained within an array.

I need to be able to alert the user if:

1. a folder they choose contain any file type not included in the array (illegal file type).
2. the folder they choose contains more than one file type included in the array (mixed legal file types).

or

3. the folder they choose contains any file types not in the array plus a file type that is in the array (mix of illegal & legal file types).

Here is the code that checks through a folder for certain file types.

```
var DARKfileList = [], FILE_TYPE, FTlen, i, SEARCH_MASK;
FILE_TYPE = ["orf", "tif", "tiff", "jpg", "jpeg"];
FTlen = FILE_TYPE.length;
for (i = 0; i < FTlen; i++) {
    SEARCH_MASK = "*." + FILE_TYPE[i];
    DARKfileList = DARKfileList.concat(DARKinputFolder.getFiles(SEARCH_MASK));
}
alert('found: ' + DARKfileList.length + ' files');
```

At the moment I have sort of achieved part 1 but it's messy as it simply checks if `DARKfileList` is empty. I can use this to alert the user that the folder they choose in empty but I would much prefer a separate check for 'illegal file types'
This is the check for empty list:

```
if (DARKfileList.length == 0)
{
    alert('Folder does not contain allowed file types!','DARK FRAME folder error');
}
```

Regards..,

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change a little bit your architecture.

You need to loop through your files and sort them by extension, and then to alert messages as you wish.

First add `Array.includes` polyfill:

```
Array.prototype.includes = function(searchElement, fromIndex) { 
    var O = Object(this);
    var len = parseInt(O.length) || 0;
    if (len === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    var n = parseInt(arguments[1]) || 0;
    var k;
    if (n >= 0) {
        k = n;
    } else {
        k = len + n;
        if (k < 0) {
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    var currentElement;
    while (k < len) {
        currentElement = O[k];
        if (searchElement === currentElement ||
                (searchElement !== searchElement && currentElement !== currentElement)) {
            return true;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Now create an object to store your allowed files:

```
var DARKfileList = {
    "orf": [],
    "tif": [],
    "tiff": [],
    "jpg": [],
    "jpeg": []
};
```

Loop through the files in the `DARKinputFolder`, and sort them:

```
var files = DARKinputFolder.getFiles();
var extension;
var illegal = [];
var illegalTypes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    extension = files[i].split('.').pop();
    if (DARKfileList.hasOwnProperty(extension)) {
        DARKfileList[extension].push(files[i]);
        continue;
    }
    if (!illegalTypes.includes(extension)) {
        illegalTypes.push(extension);
    }
    illegal.push(files[0]);
}
```

Now get the data to display about the leggal files, and concat them to one array:

```
var totalLegalFiles = [];
var foundLegalTypes = [];
for (var key in DARKfileList) {
    if (!DARKfileList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    }
    totalLegalFiles = totalLegalFiles.concat(DARKfileList[key]);
    if (DARKfileList[key].length !== 0) {
        foundLegalTypes.push(key);
    }
}
```

Finally you can display the following messages as you wish:

```
alert('found: ' + totalLegalFiles.length + ' legal files');
alert('found legal types: ' + foundLegalTypes.join(', '));
alert('found: ' + illegal.length + ' illegal files');
alert('fount illegal files: ' + illegalTypes.join(', '));
```